# Finding the string excluding the html tags

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Can I get the string without the html tags which will be displayed on the webbrowser control ?

Like I have String str = "html hello html" then I want to find the string like hello.

How can  I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to strip the html tags, like:

```
string html = "Your html string";
string x = Regex.Replace(html,@"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Here can I get the string excluding the html tags from the string in which html tags are there ?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions aren't ideal for HTML. Regular expressions are for regular text, not HTML.

Use an HTML parser library such as the free, open source [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). It comes bundled with an [HTML-to-Text converter sample](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/63084?projectName=htmlagilitypack#52176).

Comment: @Judah - Thanks for posting that, looks sweet - can't wait to check it out.

Comment: While true, in general, simply stripping tags ("things that begin with `<` and end with `>`") is quite suitable for a regex.